# How to check if a string contains a dot followed by a number in PHP

Tags: php, strpos, contain

I am trying to check if a string contains `.2`.

The following code works if I try to check if it contains a dot:

```
strpos($string, '.') !== false
```

But it doesn't work when use the following code:

```
strpos($string, '.2') !== false
```

nor

```
strpos($string, '\.2') !== false
```

Anyone an idea how to write it correctly? Thanks!

Comment: What is your `$string` ?

Comment: `strpos($string, '.2') !== false` should work as long as there is literally a `.2` in your string and no spaces between them.

Comment: try this, and you will get your matches: `preg_match('/^.*(\.\d+).*$/gm', $string, $matches);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here is a working solution:

```
$string = "this text contains the specified format: .233 and some nonsense.";
preg_match('/^.*(\.\d+).*$/m', $string, $matches);

var_dump($matches);

//returns
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(64) "this text contains the specified format: .233 and some nonsense."
  [1]=>
  string(4) ".233"
}
```

see the example at: http://regex101.com/r/eF0cU7/1